# Inbox messages auto remove once read Samsung s3

Tags: email

Have tried droid mail, k9 mail, as well as the local email app. My outlook is set to leave a copy of message on server. Emails that have been read, disappear when updating or polling for new messages. Verizon tells me gotta talk to google tech support. Does anyone know how to, or of a program, that will allow my messages to be saved locally and accessed even when outside of cell service range?

My droid and droid 2 both had no problems keeping inbox messages, read or otherwise, in my inbox.

Comment: cant' you use IMAP?

Comment: If you set Outlook to leave copies it doesn't affect other clients unless you have an Exchange mailbox. You should set this on the server (can maybe be found in webmail settings). Also, please mention the protocol you use, we're just assuming POP.